# Check if PHP array contains a non-specfic string

Tags: php, arrays

This question is not me trying to find a specific string of characters inside an array. I'd like to know the simplest way to check if a string exists in an array. Example:

```
[1,2,3] // this does NOT contain a string
[1,'two',3] // this DOES contain a string
```

The best way I can think of is looping through all the array items and running is_string() on each of them like this.

```
$array = [1,'two',3];
$hasString = false;

foreach($array as $item){
    if (is_string($item)){
        $hasString = true;
    }
}
```

This works but feels clunky. Is there a better way to do it that doesn't require looping through the array like this or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: Well you have to check element by element until you find a string, or not, to tell if there is a string in the array. So the only thing you could change is that you `break;` your loop in your code if you find a string so you can stop as soon as possible.

Comment: array_walk but it's really the same in the end.

Comment: "or is this as good as it gets" - good enough if `break` is used  and the array has large amount of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to check too:

```
<?php
function checkString($arr) {
    if (count(array_filter($arr, 'is_string'))) {
        return "Array has string";
    } else {
        return "Array hasn't any strings";
    }
}

echo checkString([1,'two',3]);
echo "<br/>";
echo checkString([1,2,3]);
```

Result:

```
Array has string
Array hasn't any strings
```

Your [Eval](https://eval.in/569556)

Comment: Thanks, that's more like what I was after. A 1 line check to see if a string exists or not. I saved it to a variable in my code to make it easier to understand and re-use: `$arrayHasString = count(array_filter($array, 'is_string'));`

Comment: I might turn it into a function actually for even better re-use. :)

Comment: `function array_has_string($array){
 return count(array_filter($array, 'is_string'));
}`

Comment: then it will return the `number` if there are more than one string in the array not `true` or `false`. Just handle that before returning

Comment: This returns booleen now `function array_has_string($array){ return count(array_filter($array, 'is_string')) ? true : false; }`

Answer (score 0):

Since it is kind of a different answer to Thamilan's answer now, I'm posting the comment as an answer.

```
function array_has_string($array){
    return count(array_filter($array, 'is_string')) ? true : false;
}

$test_1 = array_has_string([1,'two',3]);

//$test_1 = true

$test_2 = array_has_string([1,2,3]);

//$test_2 = false
```